# Regex matching JS source that's not in a string or regex literal

Tags: javascript, regex, macros, lexer

Do there exist comprehensive regular expressions that, when applied to JavaScript source code, will match all valid string literals (such as `"say \"Hello\""`) and regex literals (such as `/and\/or/`)? The expressions would have to cover all edge cases, including line breaks and escape sequences.

Alternatively, does anyone know of regexes for matching patterns *outside* of string and regex literals?

My goal is to implement a simple JavaScript syntax extension that allows macros in delimeters (e.g. `{{@foo.bar}}` or `#@foo.bar#`) to be expanded by a preprocessor. However, I'd like the macros to be processed only *outside* of literals.

For now, I'm trying to accomplish this using just string replacement, without having to augment an existing JavaScript lexer/parser.

This JavaScript preprocessor will itself be implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: I think this is too much for regexes. Consider `var foo = "//" //  /"(?:\\.|[^"])*"/`. Where do the strings, comments and regex literals start and end?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, I think your comment is the correct answer. You can't get around implementing a full-blown parser here. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. (I ended up deciding against macros and just went with specific variable naming conventions, so I'm using pure JavaScript syntax.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is too much for regexes.

Consider `var foo = "//" // /"(?:\\.|[^"])*"/`. Where do the strings, comments and regex literals start and end? You would need to write a complete JavaScript parser to cover all edge cases. Of course, the parser will be using regexes...

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex that I've been using to match quoted strings which is pretty good since it should work with almost all engines since it does not require backtracking or backreferences or any of that voodoo. This will match all text INSIDE literals.

```
"(\\.|[^"])*"
```

Depending on the engine, it might support non capturing groups. In that case you can use

```
"(?:\\.|[^"])*"
```

and it should be faster.

Comment: +1, but it might be a good idea to include the backslash in the negated character class `"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"` as a means of protection against invalid input like `"\\\"`. Also, `[\s\S]` should probably replace the dot, so multi-line strings with backslash-escaped newlines will be parsed correctly. And of course, this solution neither takes comments nor regex literals into account. Which gets tricky when you can have quotes inside regex literals and slashes inside strings...

Comment: Yes, to be complete you need to actually parse the script to understand the contents of the actual string. This regex usually appears in the context of lexing where you'll have other expressions that would take precedence in determining if it is a comment or not. There are others out there which are longer and more complete that might be able to handle the full scenario.

Comment: `/(["'#~\/])(\\\1|[^\1])*\1/g` is another option but that will not let the opening-closing pairs to function such as in `{{this}}` and `[this]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go about doing something like the following. It will need to be improved for certain possible conditions, though.

```
var str = '"aaa \"sss \\t bbb" sss #3 ss# ((t sdsds)) ff ';
str += '/gg sdfd \/dsds/ {aaa bbb} {{ss}} {#sdsd#}';

var repeating = ['"','\\\'','/','\\~','\\#'];
// "example" 'example' /example/ ~example~ #example#
var enclosing = [];
enclosing.push(['\\{','\\}']);
enclosing.push(['\\{\\{','\\}\\}']);
enclosing.push(['\\[','\\]']);
enclosing.push(['\\(\\(','\\)\\)']);
// {example} {{example}} [example] ((example))

for (var forEnclosing='',i = 0 ; i < enclosing.length; i++) {
    var e = enclosing[i];
    var r = e[0]+'(\\\\['+e[0]+e[1]+']|[^'+e[0]+e[1]+'])*'+e[1];
    forEnclosing += r + (i < enclosing.length-1 ? '|' : '');
}
for (var forRepeating='',i = 0; i < repeating.length; i++) {
    var e = repeating[i];
    var r = e+'(\\'+e+'|[^'+e+'])*'+e;
    forRepeating += r + (i < repeating.length-1 ? '|' : '');
}

var rx = new RegExp('('+forEnclosing+'|'+forRepeating+')','g');
var m = str.match(rx);
try { for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) console.log(m[i]) }
catch(e) {}
```

Outputs:

```
"aaa "sss \t bbb"
#3 ss#
((t sdsds))
/gg sdfd /dsds/
{aaa bbb}
{{ss}}
{#sdsd#}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get with a regex is to have one regex that matches EITHER a string literal (single- or double-quoted) OR a regex OR a comment (OR whatever else might contain bogus matches) OR one of your macro thingies:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
|
'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'
|
/[^/\\]*(?:\\.[^/\\]*)*/[gim]*
|
/\*[^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/
|
#@(\w+\.\w+)#
```

If group #1 contains anything after the match, it must be what you're looking for.  Otherwise, ignore this match and go on to the next one.